# Segmentation Fault with linked list node assignment in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm probably missing something pretty simple again but too many hours in the lab have left me unable to see what I did wrong here. I'm attempting to build a linked list of all the characters being read in from a file by creating a list and appending new nodes to it as new characters are read in until the end of file.

First some background, here's the code for the node structure:

```
typedef struct node
{
//each node holds a single character
char data;
//pointer to the next node in the list
struct node *next;
}node;
```

Through the use of a couple of printf statements I've managed to narrow the issue down to somewhere in this block of code.

```
FILE *infile = fopen("data.txt", "r");

int c;
int counter = 0;
node *head, *current = NULL;

//Get the count of our original rules and create the list
do{

   node *item = new node();

  c = fgetc(infile);      

  if(c == '\n'){
counter ++;
  }

  printf("From infile: %c \n", c);

item->data = c; 
item->next = NULL;

printf("Item data: %c", item->data);

if (head == NULL){
  head  = current =  item;
}
else {    
  current->next = item;
  current = item;
}

}while( c != EOF);
```

I'm not certain where it is but I know it's in there. If i could just get another pair of eyes to point out where this is going wrong I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not intialize `head` here:

```
node *head, *current = NULL;
```

so it will have an indeterminate value, so most likely this check is failing:

```
if (head == NULL){
```

and therefore neither *head* nor *current* would be properly initialized.

If you are using *C++11* then you should be using [nullptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) instead of `NULL`.

Comment: this is c++ ideally we should be using `nullptr`

Comment: @Mgetz Ideally, we shouldn't be using `fgetc`, `printf`, `FILE*`, naked pointers and redundant `struct`s as well ;)

Comment: That's got it! Thanks! Whew, if I missed that it might be time for a little break.